# How to apply tablerate shipping on discounted subtotal?

Tags: shipping, shipping-methods, discount, table-rates

How to apply tablerate shipping on discounted subtotal ? In default magento it apply shipping on actual subtotal. If any coupon applied then shipping should be calculated on discounted amount.

For example,

These are shipping rates-

> Country | Region/State | Zip/Postal Code | Order Subtotal (and above)
>   | Shipping Price
>
> USA | * | * | 0 | 4.5
>
> USA | * | * | 25.01 | 10
>
> USA | * | * | 50.01 | 11

Your subtotal is : $55, and coupon discount is: $15

By default magento will pick shipping as $11 on subtotal=$55

But after making all above changes it should pick shipping as $10 on discounted subtotal i.e. $55-$15 = $40

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Answer (score 1):

To do this we need to override some magento core files.

Override **Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate**

In your config.xml file add below code -

```
<models>
    <shipping>
        <rewrite>
            <carrier_tablerate>Yourpackage_Yourmodule_Model_Carrier_Tablerate</carrier_tablerate>
         </rewrite>
    </shipping>
</models>
```

Create Tablerate.php file in your module of below path- Yourpackage/Yourmodule/Model/Carrier/Tablerate.php and rewrite function collectRates() as follows -

```
class Yourpackage_Yourmodule_Model_Carrier_Tablerate extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Tablerate
{
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        .............

        $rate = $this->getRate($request); //after this line of function add below code.......

        if ($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() < 0) {
            $request->setPackageValueWithDiscount(0);
        }
        $originalPackageValue = $request->getPackageValue();
        $request->setPackageValue($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount());
        $rate = $this->getRate($request);
        $request->setPackageValue($originalPackageValue);

        .............

    }
}
```

Then we need to make some changes for discount calculation of default magento -

Override **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address**

In your config.xml file add below code -

```
<models>
    <sales>
        <rewrite>
            <quote_address>Yourpackage_Yourmodule_Model_Sales_Quote_Address</quote_address>
        </rewrite>
     </sales>
</models>
```

Then Create Address.php file in your module of below path- Yourpackage/Yourmodule/Model/Sales/Quote/Address.php and rewrite function getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() as follows -

```
class Yourpackage_Yourmodule_Model_Sales_Quote_Address extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address
{
    public function getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount()
    {
        $baseDiscountAmount = 0;
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address')->getCollection()
           ->addFieldToFilter('quote_id', $this->getQuoteId())
           ->addFieldToFilter('customer_address_id', $this->getCustomerAddressId())
           ->getFirstItem();
        $quoteData = $quote->getData();
        if ($this->getBaseDiscountAmount() != "") {
            return $this->getBaseSubtotal()+$this->getBaseDiscountAmount();
        } else {
            if (isset($quoteData['base_discount_amount'])) {
                $baseDiscountAmount = $quoteData['base_discount_amount'];
            } 
            return $this->getBaseSubtotal()+$baseDiscountAmount;
        }
    }
}
```

Now configure Tablerate shipping from admin. Create a coupon. Apply coupon code on frontend and do checkout and check shipping rates over there.

For example these are shipping rates-

**Country | Region/State | Zip/Postal Code | Order Subtotal (and above) |   Shipping Price**

> USA | *   |  *  |  0  |  4.5
>
> USA | *   |  *  |  25.01 |  10
>
> USA | *   |  *  |  50.01  |  11

Your subtotal is : $55, and coupon discount is: $15

By default magento will pick shipping as **$11** on subtotal=$55

But after making all above changes it will pick shipping as **$10** on discounted subtotal i.e. $55-$15 = $40

Comment: Trying to get this to work on magento 1.9.x but I am getting below errors, any idea? Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getCollection() on boolean in /home/mg/domains/x.nl/public_html/devi/includes/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Quote.php:518 Stack trace: #0